# Hibernate -- Using @SecondaryTable, @OneToMany

Tags: hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

(Simplified Example below)

I'm trying to map one POJO class with 2 DB tables and also creating a OneToMany association. Here is how the class looks like..

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "external_data")
@SecondaryTable(name = "external_data_hierarchy")
public class ExternalData  {

  private int externalDataId;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinTable(name = "external_data_hierarchy")
  @JoinColumn(name = "external_data_parent_id")
  private List<ExternalData> children;
..

}
```

Here are the tables..

```
mysql> desc external_data;
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| external_data_id | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.06 sec)

mysql> desc external_data_hierarchy;
+----------------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                      | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| external_data_hierarchy_id | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| external_data_parent_id    | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| external_data_child_id     | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+----------------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Note: "external_data_parent_id" and "external_data_child_id" columns refer external_data.external_data_id column.
```

As you can tell, I'm trying to store parent-child relationship in a different table.
Now, when I try create() on ExternalData without setting the children, it works.
When I try to fetch this created data using ExternalData.getChildren() I get the following exception..

```
[main] WARN  in [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter.logExceptions(JDBCExceptionReporter.java:100)] - SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22
[main] ERROR in [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter.logExceptions(JDBCExceptionReporter.java:101)] - Unknown column 'externalda0_1_.external_data_id' in 'on clause'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Added @OneToMany for the code snippet. It was missed as a part of writing the description.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear which relation there is between the tables. What's the use of the `external_data_child_id` column?

What I can say is that:

- You don't have a `@OneToMany` annotation on the children field
- This OneToMany is either mapped thanks to a join column, or thanks to a join table. Not both.
- Since you're using a secondary table, you should specify in which table each column or JoinColumn is, by using the table attribute of the annotation (or at least, you should specify it when the column or join colums is not in the primary table).

See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapping-declaration-join for explanations on how `SecondaryTable` should be used, and http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#collections-mapping for explanations on OneToMany associatios.

Comment: Added @OneToMany for the code snippet. It was missed as a part of writing the description.